# Conformation of six-membered ring constituting a bridged compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers

What is the conformation of the cyclohexane ring constituting [2.2.1]-bicycloheptane? 
Is it boat or twisted boat? Is that conformation abundant in other bicyclic systems containing a cyclohexane ring?

[image]

EDIT: From [Modern Organic Synthesis by Zweifel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716772663) I took the following image:
[image]

which is in contradiction with current answers. Can anyone account for this observation?

Comment: Please be so kind and mark the edits in the question, so it is obvious how our argumentation builds up.

Comment: @ssavec No, definitely not. Please never mark any edits whatsoever, that is what the edit history is for. A question should always stand as is, not as a chronological build up. The extension that is now introduced does hardly make any sense to me, as I don't know what are the current answers, and I don't know how it even relates to the first question.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン You got the point. The added question does not relate to the original one at all. By substantially modyfing the question, OP rendered the existing answer (mine) look very incomplete. I don't think the question should become more complicated after it was answered.

Comment: The question was: Conformation of six-membered ring constituting a bridged compound. I provided [2.2.1]-bicycloheptane as an example with the follow-up questions: Is it boat or twisted boat? Is that conformation abundant in OTHER bicyclic systems containing a cyclohexane ring?" I've got the answer for [2.2.1]-bicycloheptane, it is boat, but what about other systems. I provided an example where boat isn't the most stable conformation. The correct conformation for  just [2.2.1]-bicycloheptane doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ssavec I agree with that. Once an answer is given, it is better to ask a new question and provide a link for context.

Comment: The question: "Is that conformation abundant in OTHER bicyclic systems containing a cyclohexane ring?" wasn't added later and when I first asked the question there wasn't any problem with it. Xumuk gave an answer that all systems adopt a boat conformation and to disprove it I edited the question. A complete answer is still missing.

Answer (score 7):

According to structure determined by electron diffraction, norbornane is present in bridged boat conformation. http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01014a032, see Figure.

[image: Figure 10 of the article]

Norbornane and its derivatives are often used for studying effect of equatorial and axial substitution of cyclohexane and is considered rigid. 
Therefore, I don't expect significant population of the second conformer you sketched.

**Edit:**
For the [2.2.2]bicyclooctane (not the lactone mentioned in question), both conformers are known in crystalographic database.

Bear in mind, that bicyclooctane constist of three hypothetical cyclohexanes, possibly equivalent by symmetry.

For any compound of interest, you should find enough data in crystallographic database, but I'd expect all reasonable conformations to exist.

Comment: That's not the full answer. Is that conformation abundant in other bicyclic systems containing a cyclohexane ring like bicyclo[2.2.2]octane?

Comment: Which one is lower in energy?

Comment: I need solid evidence because there are contradictory answers here.

Comment: @Marko If you need solid evidence, than find it yourself.

Comment: I need for one of these answers so I can accept it. Geoff said that the most stable conformation for bicyclo[2.2.2]octane is twist-boat, XuMuk said that it is boat and you didn't give a definite answer on that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Norbornane, as mentioned by the other answers forces the cyclohexane ring into a prototypical "boat" conformation. The bridging carbon creates two five-membered rings in the low-energy envelope or "pucker" conformation:

[image]

Put simply, the 1-carbon bridging system creates a very rigid system. While there are many eclipsed C-H interactions, changing conformation would require stretching bonds or angles - distortions that are much higher in energy.

In larger bicycloalkanes, like bicyclo[2.2.2]octane, there is now more conformational flexibility to adopt a twist-boat conformation:

[image]

Notice that from the bridgehead carbons, there are *many* eclipsing interactions. In Avogadro, I can *watch* this all-boat conformation twist into the twist-boat:

[image]

While it's important to do conformational analysis for every molecule (small interactions can change the low-energy conformer), I would guess most of the larger bicycloalkanes to adopt twist-boat configurations.

Comment: So which conformation is the more stable one for bicyclo[2.2.2]octane?

Comment: It's twist-boat - you can see the twist in the final image (of bicycle[2.2.2]octane).

Comment: Relative energy of hydrocarbon conformers is reasonably tricky question, involving among others long range weak interactions, dynamic effects and symmetry. That's why I (as computational chemist) tried to avoid answer based on calculations. BTW, how large is the energy difference of those?

Answer (score 2):

Your molecule is "bicyclo[2.2.1]heptane", also called "norbornane".

And it looks like:
[image: Simple 3d of bicycloheptane]

Coordinates:

```
C    -0.336900000000      0.382800000000      0.560000000000
C     1.186600000000      0.194300000000      0.678100000000
C     1.458300000000     -0.983300000000     -0.277900000000
C     0.054500000000     -1.313600000000     -0.817600000000
C    -0.397400000000     -0.196100000000     -1.775400000000
C    -0.669200000000      0.981300000000     -0.819300000000
C    -0.819800000000     -1.054000000000      0.403500000000
H    -0.777400000000      0.930600000000      1.394100000000
H     1.468700000000     -0.067200000000      1.698900000000
H     1.738100000000      1.093400000000      0.400200000000
H     1.874300000000     -1.831700000000      0.267200000000
H     2.157900000000     -0.722600000000     -1.072900000000
H    -0.028300000000     -2.315100000000     -1.241800000000
H    -1.309100000000     -0.480900000000     -2.302600000000
H     0.360200000000      0.039800000000     -2.523700000000
H    -1.716400000000      1.283000000000     -0.870400000000
H    -0.059000000000      1.855400000000     -1.049900000000
H    -1.889000000000     -1.133000000000      0.198000000000
H    -0.570700000000     -1.688700000000      1.255400000000
```

Could you draw the 3d of twisted boat? (it definitely is not the minimal energy conformer)

I can try to calculate the energy of the conformers by quantum-chemistry, but there is a problem - minimisation leads to the boat conformation.

This is MO of norbornane:
[image]

This is 3d structure of 2-Oxabicyclo(2.2.2)octan-3-one ((1s,4s)-2-oxabicyclo[2.2.2]octan-3-one):
[image]

and xyz coordinates:

```
C     0.863100000000      0.683400000000      0.628700000000
C     1.100200000000     -0.847300000000      0.586700000000
C    -0.188300000000     -1.567200000000      0.104800000000
C    -1.274300000000     -0.508200000000     -0.211400000000
C    -0.760200000000      0.456300000000     -1.309800000000
C     0.533400000000      1.154500000000     -0.810100000000
C    -0.391200000000      0.927800000000      1.487000000000
O    -0.385000000000      1.631600000000      2.492800000000
O    -1.472000000000      0.267900000000      0.979400000000
H     1.721200000000      1.214600000000      1.041700000000
H     1.383200000000     -1.208500000000      1.576700000000
H     1.934600000000     -1.081400000000     -0.074900000000
H    -0.549400000000     -2.249900000000      0.875300000000
H     0.019000000000     -2.174800000000     -0.776900000000
H    -2.210400000000     -0.981200000000     -0.509400000000
H    -1.525500000000      1.199400000000     -1.538800000000
H    -0.568800000000     -0.088500000000     -2.235000000000
H     0.404800000000      2.237900000000     -0.827600000000
H     1.365600000000      0.933900000000     -1.479200000000
```

I don't know what authors call for "twist boat", but for compounds, you are asking about, there is definitely only one conformer!

For visualisation these geometries you can use a lot of software - chemcraft, VMD, avogadro, pymol...

Comment: That's not the full answer. Is that conformation abundant in other bicyclic systems containing a cyclohexane ring like bicyclo[2.2.2]octane?

Comment: @Marko This conformation is very solid, as said ssavec - population of other conformations is almost zero.

Comment: I will edit my question to prove my point.

Comment: @Marko It is on page 35, before 2.2. "The lactone moeity acts as a stereochemical bridge, maintaining the hydroxyl and 
carboxylic acid groups in a cis relationship.  I think there is little mistake in what to call "twist boat".

Comment: It is drawn so, but it could be a mistake.

Comment: @Marko Please, try to draw it in 3d or make in any chemical constructor. You will see, twisted almost impossible.

Comment: Here: http://www.bluffton.edu/~bergerd/models/newman3.html I don't see what it would be so improbable.

Comment: @Marko your link is totally irrelevant for the lactone issue.

Comment: @Marko I completely agree with you - it is possible for simple C6H12 (Cyclohexane). But I insist in building the model of bicyclo[2.2.2]octane or 2-Oxabicyclo(2.2.2)octan-3-one! Simple ring - another situation.

Comment: I've put the link because one can easily compare the boat and twist-boat conformations of simple cyclohexane and to prove that there shouldn't be that much difference as you suggested.

Comment: @Marko What kind of proof do you need? Citation from another book will be enough?

Comment: Book, publication, calculation...

Comment: @Marko Ok http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002228609185011Q (X-Ray study of hetero ring flexibility in norbornane, norbornene-fused 1,3-oxazin-2-thiones Structure of 5,8-methano-r-4-phenyl-c-4a, c-5,6,7,c-8,c- 8a-hexahydro-4H- 1 ,3-benzoxazin-2 (3H)-thione) there are x-ray data: https://summary.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structure-summary?sid=Elsevier&id=doi:10.1016/0022-2860%2891%2985011-Q There is a very little twist in cycle. But better have a look at: A statistical approach to the geometry of norbornane from X-ray data of substituted derivatives (10.1107/S0108768185002117)

Comment: Okay, norbornane has the boat conformation for the 6-membered ring, but bicyclo[2.2.2]octane is the disputable one. Any data about it's conformation: boat or twist-boat?

Comment: @Marko, whait, 2-Oxabicyclo(2.2.2)octan-3-one or bicyclo[2.2.2]octane?! Off-course the bicyclo[2.2.2]octane can be in twist-boat. But you in question asking about 2-Oxabicyclo(2.2.2)octan-3-one.

Comment: I am asking in general for bridged bicyclic systems. I've just found the lactone example in a textbook to prove that not all bridged bicyclic systems with 6-membered rings must adopt a boat conformation.

Comment: what software you people use to draw these molecules ?

Comment: @Lucian09474 I have used two softwares: chemcraft, it can be obtained very cheap for academic, also, there is in the Internet very old version, but without any limitations (chemcraft freeware now is very limited, but for fast and smooth pictures is on of the best and easiest). MO were calculated by Jaguar - programme of the Schrodinger -. It costs not a little money. Also, there are a lot of other, not so bad drawing/rendering software: VMD, vega zz, Mercury...